# Trying to display new random value at the click of a button without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

So, I am a novice javascript coder just barely getting my feet wet. I am building a small app that produces a randomly generated sports team name by adding one value each from a set of two arrays, a noun array and an adjective array, at the click of a button. To this moment I can generate one team name, but then instead of replacing the old team name when clicking again, the old name remains and I have to refresh the page for the button to be able to load a new team name.

I've kind of felt like the answer's a lot more simple than I think but I'm at the point where I've realized it's finals week and I can't spend all my time on this. I need help.

Here's the relevant code on codepen…
http://codepen.io/bryvl/pen/bNpgLg

**you should note that because there is no "refresh" in the code pen result pane, you may just have to type a space in the html text somewhere so the pane refreshes itself.**

Also, I'm a noob so there might actually be a way to refresh the pane…
Anyway! Your help would be **MUCH** appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you want to create a new random name everytime you click the button, you need to move the code that generates the random name inside the function that gets called when you click the button. Otherwise, you are generating a random name once then always using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `var randTeamName = ...` *inside* your `displayRandName()` function:

```
function displayRandName() {
    var randTeamName = "The" + " " + nameAdjective[Math.floor(Math.random() * nameAdjective.length)] + " " + nameNoun[Math.floor(Math.random() * nameNoun.length)];
    //Just for me to see in the editor
    console.log(randTeamName);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = randTeamName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @danielnixon! I appreciate it! It worked for the most part, but now, only in my netbeans editor connector, I am receiving a displayed value of undefined instead of just blank space before the button is clicked. It's fine in the code pen result window but not in my browser. Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 0):

when you are clicking on the button the  randTeamName is not defined to make it work you need to add it inside in displayRandName().

so try like this:

```
function displayRandName() {
    var randTeamName = "The" + " " + nameAdjective[Math.floor(Math.random() * nameAdjective.length)] + " " + nameNoun[Math.floor(Math.random() * nameNoun.length)];
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = randTeamName;
        }
```

for initial one call it inside body onload:

```
<body onload="displayRandName()">
```

Comment: The issue with this method is that I am receiving a value even before I click the button, which I don't want to happen either. I want for the user to arrive on the page without a value loading until the button is clicked.

Comment: I thought you want that by seeing:document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML=displayRandName; in your script;that's why i told to put it in onload also.otherwise rest is enough.

Comment: So, I removed the line that you said made you think that and I removed the onload, and now it's working perfectly. Thank you! But would you mind helping me understand why that worked? I think I know why… The statement I used was writing the 'displayRandName()' function value in the ID element "Output" before the function was defined, so it had a preloaded output, and then when you click the button, it loads another output. Is that right?